# @Types is not using the correct module (Typescript, http-proxy-middleware, webpack, react)

Tags: webpack, node-modules, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

I'm trying to use a similar setup to [this repo](https://github.com/gilamran/fullstack-typescript) to try and create a fullstack typescript app using React and Express.

The repo uses tsc-watch like nodemon to keep an eye on the server files, and then webpack-dev-server to host the react static files at port 8085. Meanwhile the server, running on 3000, renders the react app by proxying all static requests to /statics at 8085.

When I clone the repo everything works. However, in my own repo (where I'm trying to learn how to do a similar configuration, the server keeps throwing up this error:

> node_modules/@types/webpack-dev-server/index.d.ts

then:

> node_modules/http-proxy-middleware/dist/index"' has no exported member 'Config'.

When I go into node_modules, I can see that @types/webpack-dev-server is expecting there to be Config from http-proxy-middleware. In @types/http-proxy-middleware, there is an interface called Config. However, in the normal http-proxy-middleware node module folder, there is not, and this is what is causing the error.

My question is how do I get @types/webpack-dev-server to use @types/http-proxy-middleware, rather than just node_modules/http-proxy-middleware? Or am I missing something else entirely?

I can post code if needed.

Comment: Can you share your repo.?

Comment: hi @gilamran, yep I'll do that now

Comment: You'll see that broadly speaking it's your code - I'm skipping the manifest stuff for now just to see if I can get something working

Comment: I'm going to start a new repo because I've realised there's a submodule issue in that one

Comment: https://github.com/raph90/ts_starter_fullstack

Comment: What should I do to see your error?

Comment: @gilamran if you clone that repo and run npm run dev it should show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are few facts that might help:

- The **statics-router.ts** [is using](https://github.com/gilamran/fullstack-typescript/blob/master/src/server/routes/statics-router.ts#L10) `http-proxy-middleware`, version ["^1.0.3"](https://github.com/gilamran/fullstack-typescript/blob/master/package.json#L116)
- `webpack-dev-server` is dependent on version ["0.19.1"](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/package.json#L48)
- The `Config` on `http-proxy-middleware` was removed in version 1.
- The type definitions for version 1 are part of `http-proxy-middleware` itself (And not under @types like before)
- If you look into `/node_modules/@types/webpack-dev-server/package.json`, you will see that on the `dependencies` it has: `"@types/http-proxy-middleware": "*"`. Notice that it's dependend on the **@types** version of the `.d.ts`

It looks like typescript is searching for the type definitions under `node_modules/LIBRARY` first, and then under `@types` so it "finds" the `.d.ts` for version 1, instead of version `0.19.1` like `webpack-dev-server` requires

To solve this just add:
`"skipLibCheck": true,` to the shared `tsconfig.json`

Comment: thanks very much Gil - I'll see if I can find a way to go through @types first